# Leak reported by profiler when using NSThread. The project is compiled with ARC for Objective C and iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks

This is the way I am trying to manage my thread

```
-(void)ExecuteThread {
  @autoreleasepool {

    bInsideDifferentThread = YES;
    //some code...
    bInsideDifferentThread = NO;
  }
  [NSThread exit];
}

-(void)ThreadCallerEvent {
  NSThread *myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self     selector:@selector(ExecuteThread) object:nil];
  if (!bInsideThread)
  [myThread start];
  else
  {
    [myThread cancel];
  }
}
```

I do it this way becuase I don't want the thread to be started until it has finished working. The problem is that this is generating leaks from a non released memory allocated at `[NSThread init]`

Any ideas of how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran a fragment similar to yours and wasn't able to detect leaks; but the context is almost certainly different.  I'm really not sure what ARC is doing with `myThread` in your example when it goes out of scope.  A typical pattern for using `NSThread` would be:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(executeThread)
                         toTarget:self
                       withObject:nil];
```

in which case you're not responsible for dealing directly with the thread you are detaching.  *(Note: I changed your method name to use camel case which is the preferred method and variable naming convention in Cocoa.)*

All of the above said, managing threads are [no longer the preferred way](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html) of achieving concurrent design.  It's perfectly acceptable; but Apple is encouraging developers to migrate to GCD.  Far better to think in terms of units of work that need to be performed concurrently.

Without understanding your needs more deeply in this case, it's hard to know what advantages, if any, working directly with threads might offer you; but I would consider looking at concurrent queues/GCD more closely.  Perhaps you could simply use something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //  do your background work
});
```

and achieve both a clearer design for concurrency and avoid whatever memory management issues you are now seeing.